# Communication between android application and hardware device that transmit the LE Audio over BLE

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

We are working with hardware device that transmits the LE audio over BLE and we are trying to build an app on native android platform where it can receive the data and store the same.

For this we understand that mobile should be a sink device in order to receive the data.

We are looking forward to understand that is there any BLE class or method on android platform that help us behave as a sink device and share the continuous transmitted data from the source device to android device in order to store the data to process it later on.

Looking forward for the help.

We have done research on this points and found this thing is only done on LE Audio supported device and this LE Audio support given only on latest Android os 13.

We want to give support to other OS Device too.